# Given a Spring Boot application has OAUTH enabled, how can I make the swagger-ui visible?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

I have a Spring Boot application that uses the /oauth/token endpoint to get security tokens for RESTful api calls.

The goal is to access Swagger-UI page without having to authenticate or authorize; i.e. make it public.  I would like the future user to be able to see the swagger-ui page, get a token, and then make RESTful API calls using that token.

But first, I am having problem allowing an unauthorized user access to the swagger-ui. I have several changes to the OAuth2SecurityConfiguration trying to allow the UI page to appear.

I would expect a swagger-ui page to appear, but instead, I get a page saying the resource is not available.

The POM of the application looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>net.esc20</groupId>
    <artifactId>lms</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>test01</name>
    <description>Demo integration</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spybase</groupId>
            <artifactId>sybase-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath> ${pom.basedir}/jar/jconn4.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Adding dependencies for Swagger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Here is the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class OAuth2SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("dataSource")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("xxxxxx").roles("ADMIN").and().withUser("canvas")
                .password("xxxxx!").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
            .anonymous()
            .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/oauth/token", "/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/**", "/swagger*/**", "/webjars/**")
            .permitAll()    
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/swagger-ui.html")
            .permitAll();
    }
@Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    // Activates persistent token storage
    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() throws SQLException {
        System.out.println(
                "Setting token store!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
        // System.out.println("Setting token store!!!!!: " + new
        // JdbcTokenStore(dataSource()));
        // return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler(TokenStore tokenStore) {
        TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler handler = new TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler();
        handler.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        handler.setRequestFactory(new DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory(clientDetailsService));
        handler.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public ApprovalStore approvalStore(TokenStore tokenStore) throws Exception {
        TokenApprovalStore store = new TokenApprovalStore();
        store.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        return store;
    }
```

And here is the Swagger config file I am using ->

```
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
          .select()
          .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
          .paths(PathSelectors.any())
          .build();
    }

    private ApiInfo getApiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfo(
                "TITLE",
                "DESCIPRION",
                "VERSION",
                "TERMS OF SERVICE URL",
                new Contact("NAME","URL","EMAIL"),
                "LICENSE",
                "LICENSE URL",
                null
        );
    }
}
```

When I try to access swagger ui, I get this
[image: Accessing Swagger-UI]

Answer (score 0):

Try to override configure method in your `OAuth2SecurityConfiguration` which accept argument with `WebSecurity` type and
do all what you need.

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/here-your-ignoring-path");
}
```

Comment: Which class should contain the configure() method?

Comment: OAuth2SecurityConfiguration

Comment: Yes, sorry that did not say about that before. I will edit the comment